# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

Tags: python, parsing, attributeerror

My code simply uses BeautifulSoup parser to fetch the top movies from IMDB
website.

The code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
url = "http://www.imdb.com/chart"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
tr = soup.findChildren("tr")
tr = iter(tr)
next(tr)
for movie in tr:
    title = movie.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('a').contents[0]
    year = movie.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('span',{'class':'secondaryInfo'}).contents[0]
    rating = movie.find('td',{'class':'ratingColumn imdbRating'}).find('strong').contents[0]
    row = title + "-" + year + " " + " " + rating
    print(row)
```

It gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imdb_scrap.py", line 12, in <module>
    year = movie.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('span',{'class':'secondaryInfo'}).contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

The given code did run for the first time with incomplete output and the error while it didn't run at all later.

Sample output:

```
Stalker-(1979)  8.1
Paper Moon-(1973)  8.1
The Maltese Falcon-(1941)  8.1
The Truman Show-(1998)  8.1
Hachi: A Dog's Tale-(2009)  8.1
Le notti di Cabiria-(1957)  8.1
The Princess Bride-(1987)  8.1
Kaze no tani no Naushika-(1984)  8.1
Munna Bhai M.B.B.S.-(2003)  8.1
Before Sunrise-(1995)  8.1
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2-(2011)  8.0
The Grapes of Wrath-(1940)  8.0
Prisoners-(2013)  8.0
Rocky-(1976)  8.0
Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens-(2015)  8.0
Touch of Evil-(1958)  8.0
Sholay-(1975)  8.0
Catch Me If You Can-(2002)  8.0
Gandhi-(1982)  8.0
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It means the `.find('span',{'class':'secondaryInfo'})` call didn't find anything and returned `None`. You are making assumptions about the HTML structure that obviously aren't always true.

Comment: The output of a successful run is not nearly as interesting as the *input* for a failed run.

Comment: There are no spans in `<td class="titleColumn">` element that I can see.

Comment: @MartijnPieters check this out: `  <td class="titleColumn">
      1.
      <a href="/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042102&pf_rd_r=196N5H2ZT49DTFKK8G29&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1"
title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman" >The Shawshank Redemption</a>
        <span class="secondaryInfo">(1994)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="ratingColumn imdbRating">
            <strong title="9.2 based on 1,844,955 user ratings">9.2</strong>
    </td>`

Comment: Sure, but not in the *first `tr`* that I just loaded. The year appears to be optional. Test for the span to be there first.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the error lies in

```
.find('span',{'class':'secondaryInfo'}).contents[0]
```

This might not be the only error but this is the first one looking at the error message that it gave you. Also I know the first half of variable year is correct because it is the same as variable title.
With this in mind it is probably because you assumed that the year is  located at [0] but this is obviously wrong because it tells you that location [0] has no info at all so if you were to print it as

```
print(movie.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find('span',{'class':'secondaryInfo'}).contents[0])
```

I would guarantee you will get None as the answer and that is NoneType which has no attributes.